# window.location.href redirects but is causing problems on the webpage

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

I'm struggling with sessions and need some help. The following is my processing.php file which starts the session and assigns session variables for a user. If the user is a participant, then they are assigned usertype='Participant' and upon login, they are redirected to a different webpage: participant.php.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
    include("connect.php");
    
    $email=$_POST['un'];
    $password=$_POST['pw'];
    
    $loginsql="SELECT * from Users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = $smeConn->query($loginsql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['first'] = $row['first'];
        
        $userID = $row['id'];
        $participantSql = "SELECT * FROM Participants WHERE user = $userID";
        $participantResult = $smeConn->query($participantSql);
    
        if ($participantResult->num_rows > 0) {
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = 'Participant';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype']; 
        }
        
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
    
?>
```

The problems come up in these lines of code on my navigate.php:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['usertype']) && $_SESSION['usertype']=="Participant"){
         echo "<script>location.href='https://beroz.pwcswebdev.com/SMU_Part5/signMeUp04_v5-1-3/participant.php';</script>";
     }
?>
```

When I login as a user who is a participant, I am redirected ONLY AFTER refreshing the webpage. After being redirected to participant.php, the page just starts rapidly refreshing over and over again. I am only able to see SOME of the navbar content, and there is no "Welcome, user" or log out button (which works on index.php). In addition to this, nothing I do gets me back to index.php, even if I refresh or close the webpage. The only way to fix this and go back to index.php is by commenting out the echo .

If you want to test it, the webpage is live at this link:
https://beroz.pwcswebdev.com/SMU_Part5/signMeUp04_v5-1-3/index.php

For the login,

email: fluffy@amelie.co.fr

password: 8roadw4Y

Comment: Maybe unset the session variable when you echo the redirect script or set another one to flag that the redirect happened.

Comment: It didn't work :/ Can you explain the thought process about making a flag variable? I don't understand how it would fix the issue

Comment: Okay so I finally made some progress. I was redirecting through my nav.php, which is an include file containing the navbar information. When I put that same block of code that was giving my issues in my index.php, it navigates to participant.php and loads the page without any issues

Answer (score 1):

The reason I was getting trouble is because I was redirecting through my nav.php, which is an include file containing only the navbar information. When I put the window.location.href within my index.php, I was able to redirect with no issues.